# php variable not receiving value

Tags: php

HTML code, I added it to the form.html file.

```
<select name="find">
        <option value = "a">I'm a regular customer</option>
        <option value = "b">TV advertising</option>
        <option value = "c">Phone directory</option>
        <option value = "d">Word of mouth</option>
```

PHP code. I added to the php page that will be jumped to after submit.

```
switch($find) {
 case "a" :
    echo "<p>Regular customer.</p>";
    break;
 case "b" :
    echo "<p>TV advertising.</p>";
    break;
 case "c":
    echo "<p>Phone directory.</p>";
    break;
 case "d":
    echo "<p>Customer referred by word of mouth.</p>";
    break;
 default :
    echo "<p>We don't know.</p>";
    break;
}
```

The problem is the `$find` seems to be not working. Because the php page always show the default case and when I echo the `$find`,the whole php page won't show up, I'm new to php. please help!!

Comment: What is `$find` over here?

Comment: it will be either `$_GET['find']` or `$_POST['find']` depending on your form

Comment: please post your whole code..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this..

```
<form method="post" action="">
<select name="find">
        <option value = "a">I'm a regular customer</option>
        <option value = "b">TV advertision</option>
        <option value = "c">Phone directory</option>
        <option value = "d">Word of mouth</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>


if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$find=$_POST['find'];
switch($find) {
 case "a" :
    echo "<p>Regular customer.</p>";
    break;
 case "b" :
    echo "<p>TV advertision.</p>";
    break;
 case "c":
    echo "<p>Phone directory.</p>";
    break;
 case "d":
    echo "<p>Customer referred by word of mouth.</p>";
    break;
 default :
    echo "<p>We don't know.</p>";
    break;
}
}
```

Comment: Forgot to write $find = $_POST ['find'] hahhhhh, I'm so stupid.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to add the following?

```
$find = $_POST['find'];
above php code
```

Answer (score -1):

Try changing your file extension from `.html` to `.php`